# How to add button + to subgrid of hierarchical relation?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a hierarchical relation inside an entity X, I Have parent lookup which allow to give parent to a record of this entity, and I have created a Subgrid attached to this lookup within the same form of the entity:
The problem is that the display of the button + is unstable in this subgrid, sometimes it appears sometimes no. I dont know if this problem is related to some setting or it is a bug of dynamics crm online last version?

For information, I don't have this problem with other sub-grids.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

> if you want to add a custom button you may do this as follows

```
    function CreateButton() {
    var connectionSubGridPlusBtn = document.getElementById("Connections_addImageButton").parentNode.parentNode;
    //Connections_addImageButton is the id of + button 
    if (connectionSubGridPlusBtn != null) {
        //New Button
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "ms-crm-contextButton";
        div.innerHTML = "<button id='newButton'  type='button' style='width:80px;cursor: pointer;padding:0px' >New Button</button>";
        connectionSubGridPlusBtn.appendChild(addVendorDiv);

        //Event and url for new
        document.getElementById("newButton").onclick = function () {
           //Write codefor the button click event
        }
    }
}
```

> call this function on load of the form

Answer (score 0):

The entity has to be created before you're able to add related entities.  You can add disable all required fields, and perform a save in the onload, and you should always see the plus sign.

A slightly better solution is to override the create button for the entity, and rather than directing to the create form, perform a rest entity creation, then direct to that form.  Then you don't have to perform a save in the on load.